# fs.statSync returning inconsistent data on case sensitive network drive

Tags: node.js, windows-10, samba

I have a SAMBA share mapped as `A:` in Windows 10.  I have a folder that has two files that differ only in case.  I'm trying to get information about each file, but under nodejs I am getting inconsistent results:

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
fs.statSync("A:\\AV\\Expunged\\dups\\THUMBS.DB")
Stats {
  dev: 1338484219,
  mode: 33206,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 88091641,
  size: 9216,
  blocks: 24,
  atimeMs: 1664214925364.1516,
  mtimeMs: 989240106000,
  ctimeMs: 989240106000,
  birthtimeMs: 989240106000,
  atime: 2022-09-26T17:55:25.364Z,
  mtime: 2001-05-07T12:55:06.000Z,
  ctime: 2001-05-07T12:55:06.000Z,
  birthtime: 2001-05-07T12:55:06.000Z
}
> fs.readdirSync("A:\\AV\\Expunged\\dups\\")
[
  ...
  'PAN1700x1701.IVR',    'PTVIEWER.JAR',        'THUMBS.DB',
  'Thumbs.db',           'TMP1-D.TIF',          'TMP1-LZW.TIF',
  ...
]
> fs.statSync("A:\\AV\\Expunged\\dups\\THUMBS.DB")
Stats {
  dev: 1338484219,
  mode: 33206,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 88091641,
  size: 439296,
  blocks: 864,
  atimeMs: 1642388446544.0063,
  mtimeMs: 986494596000,
  ctimeMs: 986494596000,
  birthtimeMs: 986494596000,
  atime: 2022-01-17T03:00:46.544Z,
  mtime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z,
  ctime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z,
  birthtime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z
}
```

Note that the same inode was returned both times, but the information after the `ino` field differed the second time it was called!

Here is what I see if I use `dir` from a command prompt of the relevant files:

```
04/05/2001  11:16 AM           439,296 THUMBS.DB
05/07/2001  05:55 AM             9,216 Thumbs.db
```

On the server (Ubuntu 22.04) the relevant files have this info from `ls -li`:

```
88091598 -rwxr-xr-x 1 michael michael 439296 Apr  5  2001 THUMBS.DB
88091641 -rwxr-xr-x 1 michael michael   9216 May  7  2001 Thumbs.db
```

In one run of the same three commands from a new `node` invocation I got the same wrong results the first time but correct results the second time:

```
Stats {
  dev: 1338484219,
  mode: 33206,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 88091598,
  size: 439296,
  blocks: 864,
  atimeMs: 1642388446544.0063,
  mtimeMs: 986494596000,
  ctimeMs: 986494596000,
  birthtimeMs: 986494596000,
  atime: 2022-01-17T03:00:46.544Z,
  mtime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z,
  ctime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z,
  birthtime: 2001-04-05T18:16:36.000Z
}
```

What am I doing wrong in node such that I can't consistently get the correct file info?

Update: I get the same inconsistency if I run the above code in node under WSL2, which is surprising, because I would expect case sensitivity issues in Windows wouldn't exists in the Linux subsystem.

Comment: Perhaps a SAMBA configuration option [here](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_04.html) to offer some name mangling to deal with files that only differ in case.  Windows generally is ***case insensitive*** when opening/finding files so it's not expecting two files to have the same name but only differing in case.  Not surprising it might generate inconsistent results when the directory store violates that assumption.

Comment: @jfriend00 For what it's worth, it is possible to enable case sensitivity on NTFS on a per folder basis (`fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> enable`) and I have done this with success on a couple of external drives.  Of course this command is inapplicable to network drives.

Comment: @jfriend00 Looking at the options in the link you provided, I don't see a way to mangle *only* files that differ in case.  Mangling (all) long names or mixed case names is going to cause huge problems for the 99.999% of files that don't have "dopplegangers".